# gRpc protogen java codegen

Tags: maven, grpc

I was able to download protoc-gen-grpc-java-0.9.0 from Maven Central and use with protoc.exe via the --plugin switch.  Is protoc-gen-grpc-java-0.12.0 available as a single file download somewhere? I noticed a number of other grpc packages (grpc-core, grpc-auth) are available on Maven Central in 0.12.0 release yet for this one file I only see the 0.9.0 release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

protoc-gen-grpc-java 0.12.0 has been [available](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/grpc/protoc-gen-grpc-java/0.12.0/) since the release of the rest of 0.12.0 artifacts. However, it wasn't being indexed by search.maven.org. If you blindly tried to use 0.12.0 it would download just fine.

search.maven.org not indexing protoc-gen-grpc-java [had been going on for a while](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-831), but it was only recently that we discovered the [cause of the problem](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/1360). The fix was included in 0.13.0 and, as you noticed, it is properly indexed. As a bonus, [0.12.0 became indexed](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cio.grpc%7Cprotoc-gen-grpc-java%7C0.12.0%7CN%2FA) when we released 0.13.0.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'm up and running with 0.13.0 now.

Answer (score 0):

I see the latest 0.13.0 version on Maven Central now.